# Map to List[Tuple2] in Scala - removes duplicates?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Am trying to convert a map to list of Tuples, given a map like below

```
Map("a"->2,"a"->4,"a"->5,"b"->6,"b"->1,"c"->3)
```

i want output like

```
List(("a",2),("a",4),("a",5),("b",6),("b",1),("c",3))
```

I tried following

```
val seq = inputMap.toList  //output (a,5)(b,1)(c,3)

var list:List[(String,Int)] = Nil 
   for((k,v)<-inputMap){
       (k,v) :: list
   }  //output (a,5)(b,1)(c,3)
```

Why does it remove duplicates? I dont see other tuples that has "a" as key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since map has duplicate keys, it will remove duplicate entries while map creation itself.

```
Map("a"->2,"a"->4,"a"->5,"b"->6,"b"->1,"c"->3)
```

it will turn into,

```
Map(a -> 5, b -> 1, c -> 3)
```

so other operations will be performed on short map

Answer (score 1):

That's because a `Map` doesn't allow duplicate keys:

```scala
val map = Map("a"->2,"a"->4,"a"->5,"b"->6,"b"->1,"c"->3) 
println(map) // Map(a -> 5, b -> 1, c -> 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `Map`, whose keys are a `Set`, so you cannot have twice the same key. This is because `Map`s are dictionaries, which are made to access a value by its key, so keys MUST be unique. The builder thus keeps only the last value given with the key `"a"`.

By the way, `Map` already has a method `toList`, that do exactly what you implemented.